# Grid question for Fire Station MAP

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

How can I generate a grid that would have a quadrant like naming? Or is there a way just to rename quadrants[image] through data driven pages. Sort of Newbish but basically creating a new firestation map book and the typical row names (as see attached), does no suit us too well. I would like to see (2nd attachement with 10) more of a quadrant. How would I generate a data driven template/grid with that? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "data driven template/grid"? What is the data and how does it drive the grid you want?

Comment: I am sorry. I meant to write I am using data driven pages, based off a grid that I drew out, and Maplogic toolbar, which names the grids as pictured above.

Comment: Please consider updating the question (just click edit below the question) with that information, and anything else that might help us to help you.

Comment: Is your first image accurate in that the cells of the grid shown correspond with the page sizes and scales you want, just not the label scheme? Or do you want to further divide those cells into quadrants?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you mention you are using Maplogic, which appears to be a commercial add-on similar to the old DS Mapbook extension. My first suggestion would be to start with their help files and/or support to see if you can change the grid cell naming scheme and if so how. Their example book shows something very similar to what you are asking for - a numbered cell with a sub-grid reference. Their tool also appears to either internally use or have its own version of Data Driven Pages (DDP), so any of the following may not work correctly or apply.

Just renaming would be the simplest although possibly time consuming solution. There should be an attribute of the grid layer that is the cell name. You would just have to start an edit session and change those values to match whatever pattern you desire.  Some scripting could probably automate the task if it needed to be redone on a regular basis, but given your non-uniform grid and specific pattern goal that may take more time to write than just manually editing for a one-shot. Creative use of selections and field calculator may speed things up over editing the value for each cell.

That would work for just using the grid cells as pictured. However, if you want each of those cells to be divided into quadrants you will need to add a second grid (or fishnet, as the tool in ArcGIS is called). You can use or display as many grids as you like, but DDP will only use one to index for its pages. If each page has quadrants, your numeric grid is your DDP index and the alpha grid is simply displayed for labeling/reference.  If each quadrant is its own page, the quad grid will be your DDP index and you'll have to do some feature class/attribute manipulation to get what you want. You would create your numeric grid and get it ordered the way you want. Then you would create a second grid that quarters the first (ie, if the numeric grid cell size is 100x100, your second grid will be 50x50). Then you can either edit the cell names of that grid as above or use an overlay tool of some sort to add the numeric grid cell number as an attribute to the alpha cells that fall within it.