# Creating index layer for multiple maps in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, map-index

I am trying to create an index layer of just the area within the Orange lines. I am having difficulty creating this layer due to it not being a simple box area.

The goal is to create a index layer, with grids, so that the Data Driven Pages would be used to generate it as a mapbook for the response area for my firehouse.

Below is an image of what I am speaking about.

Any ideas?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you mean by "map index grid layer" (a graphic with sketch of what you want wouldn't be out of place).  The published definition of your keyword doesn't correspond to the question as written.

Comment: I believe what user is asking for is an alternative to the fishnet tool - see [this previous question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92591/grid-question-for-fire-station-map).

Comment: QGIS has an fTools plugin with "Vector Grid" tool. This is similar to ArcGIS Fishnet.

Comment: Or are you asking to get the extents of a group of GIS data?

Comment: Is this reworded clearer?

Comment: As far as I know, DDP does not yet support a non-rectangular map index. That said, you can generate an grid/fishnet for only those areas that intersect a target feature with [Grid Index Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Grid_Index_Features/00700000000q000000/)

Comment: @mattwilkie Any polygon feature class can be used as an index for Data Driven Pages - the features do not have to be rectangles - I am sure that this has been the case since they were introduced.

Comment: Can you replace (or add another to) your existing graphic which shows what the grid you want to create would end up looking like from a starting point of a simple polygon, please?  I think the tool @mattwilkie suggests will do the trick but I may not be picturing what you are asking for correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options here depending on some choices you make up front as far as requirements go. Both fishnet and the grid index tools can be constrained to only cover the area of a shape such as your orange outline.  Both tools give you some options the other does not. For example grid index controls overlap through DDP and a percentage, whereas fishnet you have to manually edit or specify an overlap in units.

Do you want north to remain straight up on the map page? If not, fishnet allows you to rotate the grid so if you aligned it with your western edge the grid cells would have less 'wasted' space.  However I do not recommend this for your application - whenever north isn't up or people are used to looking at things in a certain orientation, altering that orientation introduces a 'map reader orientation lag' as they get their bearings. Not ideal for emergency response.

You could use either tool to generate a grid that covers everything and then delete the cells that don't have any of your required area in them, similar to the grid you posted in a previous question.  You would just have to redo the grid labels to be sequential afterward. You could also then shift grid cells that weren't quite working - for example if that narrow (highway?) corridor at the bottom was falling on the boundary of two cells, just shift one over so it's down the middle and delete the other.

You could also draw your own custom polygons to serve as an index - as PolyGeo pointed out, it doesn't have to be rectangular or even a grid. Any set of boundary polygons can serve as an index, though you have to keep scale in mind.  There is a Strip Index tool designed for following linear features, but the concept can be adapted to any shape.

My (overview) workflow for this situation is:

1. Determine window size (based on page size and layout).
2. Determine desired map scale.
3. Multiply scale by size to determine grid cell size.
4. Run Create Fishnet (Data Management) Tool
5. Adjust grid cells for desired overlap (strips that show on adjacent pages).

That works for a regular grid. If I'm doing a strip, or detail areas, I follow Steps 1-3 to create a template polygon (sort of windowframe) I can move around the map and copy to create specific area pages. You can do a different template polygon for each scale, allowing multiple *uniform* scales in the same index layer.  You can also adjust your window boundaries for odd overlaps as needed (just be sure to keep at least one unmodified as your template).

Below is an example image from the index page of the most recent mapbook project I worked on. There are two page series (all the same pagesize) - one is an overall grid that covers the entire area at a smaller scale (not shown), the other is a detail series that provides pages at a couple of different larger scales depending on how much detail was required. Each letter is a page; the black lines are roads with mileage marker numbers. I recommend as few scales as possible for this approach, though it depends on if you really care about accurate scale and how consistent it needs to be.

[image: map grid index example]